# how to build a new player similar to youtube functionality?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, media-player, youtube-javascript-api

I would like to build a new player with following requirements like:

- Call to action : Something like showing suggestion videos at the end of the video. (Like youtube)
- Playlist : Player should have playlist (Like Youtube)
- Playback speed : Playback speed should be adjusted as like in VLC media player
- Closed Captioning : Something like closed captions which comes at the play time of a video in youtube
- Should play from various service providers CDN

Will youtube's documentation on https://developers.google.com/youtube help us in any way with this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of open source and/or free players that already do this, so there would be no reason to build your own; have a look at [Flowplayer](https://flowplayer.org/), [JW Player](http://www.jwplayer.com/), [videoJS](http://www.videojs.com/), and others that a Google search pull up. If you're insistent on building your own, the YouTube documentation may give you some ideas as to what to look for in your own player, but the function calls will be different as you'll have to use the javascript media APIs (for HTML5 video).